# Microsoft visual studio 2015 community crash when start installing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation

I'm trying to install `Visual Studio 2015` on my laptop
but this error crashes always, below this image some several solution I've tried

[image]

1- Clear Fonts folder -- Not Working.

2- Changing `%WinDir%` value in `regedit`-- Not Working.

3- Lunch as administrator -- Not Working.

4- update my OS -- Not working.

**Update : Add Error Stack**

```
[0A98:1DF4][2017-05-08T17:59:22]e000: MUX:  ERROR: The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Media.FontFamily' threw an exception.
[0A98:1DF4][2017-05-08T17:59:22]e000: MUX:  Stack:    at System.Windows.Media.Typeface..ctor(FontFamily fontFamily, FontStyle style, FontWeight weight, FontStretch stretch)
   at MS.Internal.Text.DynamicPropertyReader.GetTypeface(DependencyObject element)
   at MS.Internal.Text.TextProperties.InitCommon(DependencyObject target)
   at MS.Internal.Text.TextProperties..ctor(FrameworkElement target, Boolean isTypographyDefaultValue)
   at System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.GetLineProperties()
   at System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.EnsureTextBlockCache()
   at System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Decorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisual()
   at System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double requestedTop, Double requestedLeft, Double requestedWidth, Double requestedHeight)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowImpl()
   at System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindow()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Window.Show()
   at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.RunUI(ViewModelCommonUi viewModel)
   at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.InternalRun()
   at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.Run()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
[0A98:1DF4][2017-05-08T17:59:22]e000: MUX:  Exception: Info: InnerException: Info:
[0A98:1DF4][2017-05-08T17:59:22]e000: MUX:  ERROR: Not a valid Win32 FileTime.
Parameter name: fileTime
[0A98:1DF4][2017-05-08T17:59:22]e000: MUX:  Stack:    at System.DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(Int64 fileTime)
   at System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(String path)
   at System.IO.Directory.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(String path)
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.FontSource.GetLastWriteTimeUtc()
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.FamilyCollection.AddPhysicalFamilyToList(FontSource fontSource, List`1 familyList, SortedDictionary`2 familyNameList, SortedList`2 frequentStrings)
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.FamilyCollection.BuildFamilyList(List`1& familyList, SortedDictionary`2& familyNameList, SortedList`2& frequentStrings)
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.FamilyCollection.MS.Internal.FontCache.IFontCacheElement.AddToCache(CheckedPointer newPointer, ElementCacher cacher)
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.HashTable.Lookup(IFontCacheElement e, Boolean add)
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.CacheManager.Lookup(IFontCacheElement e)
   at System.Windows.Media.FontFamily.PreCreateDefaultFamilyCollection()
   at System.Windows.Media.FontFamily..cctor()
    enter code here
```

Comment: [configure Windows 7 to generate a crash dump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638(VS.85).aspx) (dumptype to 2 to get full dump) and analyze the dmp in windbg.exe by running **!analyze -v**

Comment: You can have a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed and check for invalid characters in the font paths and invalid files timestamps in the fonts, run the fixit tool: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed. Make sure windows update is up-to-date, temporarily disable any antivirus, clean up %temp%, then re-run the VS installer as administrator.

Comment: If the above not works, please backup the registry table and old fonts, and like this similar issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d025e58c-1591-4c0a-9955-869ce77ed425/vs-premium-2012-installation-failure-on-windows-7?forum=vssetup to replace them with the good one from another windows 7 computer with the same OS version.

Comment: I've trying to check valid name and date for fonts manually but i failed .. after your comment I delet fonts by using this command del /f /s /q /a "C:\Windows\fonts\*.*" in cmd as administrator and cleaning registry fonts [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts] and install fonts from other pc is solved the problem @Sara-MSFT please post your answer to accept it as a solution ... Thanks for your help

Comment: @BlackRoot, it's my pleasure and so glad to hear that your issue is solved, I added the comments as reply, and you can mark it when you have free time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please backup the registry table *([ HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts])* and old fonts ( *c:\windows\Fonts*), and like [this similar issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d025e58c-1591-4c0a-9955-869ce77ed425/vs-premium-2012-installation-failure-on-windows-7?forum=vssetup) to replace them with the good one from another windows 7 computer with the same OS version, then re-run the VS installer as administrator to test it.

1. Get c:\windows\Fonts content from another 64-Bit Windows 7 Machine.
2. Get relevant registry entry from another machine
3. Delete all fonts file use this command in administrator mode del /f /s /q /a "C:\Windows\fonts*.*"
4. Delete entry from Registry
5. Copy Fonts to  c:\windows\Fonts
6. Put into the registry the fonts executing the exported registry key
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
7. Reboot the machine

Comment: to add more info to this answer for deleting all fonts file use this command in administrator mode `del /f /s /q /a "C:\Windows\fonts*.*"` ,, it is butter to Clear `%TEMP%` Folder ,, please add this 2 info to have a powerful complete answer (y)

Comment: Thanks for you you save my day.